# "Cannot transition to abstract state'" when trying to highlight parent in sidebar

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-router

I am using angular UI-Router and bootstrap collapse panels to build a sidebar for a style guide. My sidebar as is "works" but I'm getting a

> `Error: Cannot transition to abstract state 'parent'`

when clicking the child states. In my real solution there are many parents with child groupings and the parents truly are abstract *(i.e. they don't represent a physical page or state)*. I know I can't link directly to the parent states, and I don't believe I am, I just need to set their `ui-sref` in the parent panel so that I can get the parent to stay open by setting the `ui-sref-active` attribute.

I have an example running on plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/bnvGcaOvzW4que8g3vh7?p=preview

code for reference:

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.router'])
        .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
            $stateProvider
                .state('home', {
                    url: "/",
                    templateUrl: "layout.html"
                })
                .state('parent', {
                    abstract: true,
                    url: '/parent',
                    templateUrl: "layout.html"
                })
                .state('parent.child', {
                    url: "/child",
                    templateUrl: "child.html"
                })
        });
```

layout.html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <a ui-sref="home">Home</a>
           <div class="panel-group" id="sidebar">
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                      <a data-toggle="collapse"  data-parent="#sidebar" data-target="#parent"
                   class="collapsed">Parent</a>
                  </h4>
                </div>
              <div id="parent" ui-sref="parent" class="panel-collapse collapse" ui-sref-active="in">
                <div class="list-group">
                    <a ui-sref="parent.child" ui-sref-active="active" class="list-group-item">Child</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <div ui-view></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

**Short Answer:**

Just remove `ui-sref="parent"` from your code. This particular `ui-sref` attribute is not required in order for `ui-sref-active` to work as you expect.

**Long Answer:**

`ui-sref-active` works by finding all child elements with a `ui-sref` and adding these elements to a `states` array attached to the element. On `$stateChangeSuccess`, each element loops through this array and if a state is found that matches the array, then the class is applied.

As an example:

```
<ul>
    <li ui-sref-active="open">
        <a ui-sref="app.home">Link</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a ui-sref="app.home.this"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a ui-sref="app.home.that"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a ui-sref="app.home.whatever"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a ui-sref="temp"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In the above example, assume `app` is an abstract. All 4 of those links will trigger the `open` class on the parent element, as they are contained within. It doesn't matter that they are not all part of the `app.home` structure.

Comment: You're right that does work at a simple HTML tag level (with ul/li), and it makes perfect sense. For whatever reason, it does not work in my example using the bootstrap collapse panel. I [forked the plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/M4JZP7iQV5oj9u7c8EZs?p=preview) to show. I think it might have to do with bootstrap's javascript getting in the way.

Comment: I'm not following. It appears that all directives are working in that Plunker?

Comment: It is working for the list-item section in the way you described above, successfully adding the `text-uppercase` class. But in the bootstrap collapse panel example above it, when clicking on the child page, the collapse panel does not stay open after the new page. The `ui-sref-active="in"` is not successfully added to the `class="panel-collapse collapse"` attribute.